# Antd Select handle functions types typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a question.
So Antd provides custom Select input and with it some functions like `onSelect`, `onChange` etc.
I'm using `onSelect` and this is what this function passes as arguments:

```
(JSX attribute) onSelect?: ((value: string | number | LabeledValue, option: OptionData | 
OptionGroupData) => void) | undefined
```

So my `handleSelect` function gets 2 arguments, the first is the value of an option itself and the second one is the whole option tag with all data.
I was able to figure out value type and import it from antd but for option I cannot find any suitable files to import it type from, so I'm getting an error because I can't set my second arg type properly

```
const handleSelect: (value: SelectValue, option: any) => void
```

And the option arg she be type:

```
option: OptionData | OptionGroupData) => void) | undefined
```

How am I suppose to set this type, where can I get it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if implementations changed since this question was made, but we solved importing:

`import { OptionData, OptionGroupData } from "rc-select/lib/interface"`

And where needed the type

`option: OptionData | OptionGroupData | undefined`

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Yeah the implementation must've changed becaouse at time I was writing these questions there was no types for options provided or I was too blind to find it, thanks once more :)